# How to copy bytes from pointer into a char[]?

Tags: c, mmap, memcpy, fat32

I'm currently trying to read/write a FAT32 disk.img. I use mmap() to map disk.img into memory. Here is the memory value represents in bytes:

```
4353 4333 3630 4653 0200 0000 1900 0000

0002 0000 0032 0000 0035 0000 0008 0000
```

As you can see, if I print `address[0]` and `address[1]`, I get `67` and `83`. This is correct, but when I try to print `address[8]` and `address[9]`, I get only `2` and `0`, not `02` and `00`. Which means that the digit 0 before 2 in `address[8]` and the first 0 in `address[9]` has been dropped.

Is there anyway I can copy the value of `address[8]` and `address[9]` together into one `char[]`? For example `char s[] = "0200"`. I have tried `memcpy()`, but the error I got is following:

```
warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing
  'char' to parameter of type 'const void *' [-Wint-conversion]
    memcpy(a, address[8], len);
              ^~~~~~~~~~
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/secure/_string.h:62:33: note: 
  expanded from macro 'memcpy'
            __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, __VA_ARGS__, __darwin_obsz...
```

Which seems like that I cannot copy type char* but only type const void* to my destination. Thank you very much for the help ahead!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
    struct stat buffer;
    int status = fstat(fd, &buffer);
    char* address = mmap(NULL, buffer.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("address[0] is : %d\n", address[0]);
    printf("address[1] is : %d\n", address[1]);
    printf("address[8] is : %d\n", address[8]);
    printf("address[9] is : %d\n", address[9]);
}
```

Comment: The "problem" with leading zeroes being dropped is entirely by-design: `printf("%d")` will not print leading zeroes. The zeroes are still there because your values haven't magically shrunk from `int64_t` to `int8_t` for example.

Comment: You do know that dropping leading zeros is a display issue not a storage issue right?

Comment: BTW, how are you printing `4353 4333 3630 46...`? It's not usual to print decimal digits into groups of 4, what do they represent exactly? Why not print using hexadecimal instead?

Comment: You can add zeropadding to printf, for consistency if that is all you need. `printf("address[9] is : %02d\n", address[9]);`

Comment: printf %d format does not print the first zeros. the read value is ok. if you want to print hexa code. "%02x", (unsigned char)address[i]. and you'd better use unsigned char * instead of char*.

Comment: When I subtract two numbers like 37 and 21 I get 16. But when I subtract 18 and 10 I get 8! How can I fix it so 18 - 10 is 08?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, I have found the printf() problem. I'm still at the very beginning of C. Moreover, Is there any way I can put address[8] and address[9] into a char[] array? Like s[] = "0200"? I don't know how to figure it out. I tried memcpy(), but I cannot copy them into an array as I want since the parameter address is defined as char*. @Dai I just open the disk.img file with an editor, the bytes represent the values of a disk.img for FAT32.

Comment: @ZeroSun `memcpy` (and `memmove`) copies bytes in memory, not the textual representation you see printed. What you seem to want is to convert the byte values (2 and 0 for `address[8]` and `address[9]`) to 2-byte hexadecimal strings like you see in a hex editor (0200). For that, you want the `snprintf` function. Please understand that when you do `snprintf(a, 3, "%02X", 1);` you get 3 bytes: `30 31 00`. `30` is the hex value representing the character '0', `31` is the hex value representing the character '1', and `00` is the hex value representing the "null character" at the end of strings in C

Comment: If you specify `%02X`, then you'll need 2 bytes in the array `a`, plus 1 for the null character, meaning a total of 3 bytes (`char a[3];`). If you specify `%02X%02X` then you'd need 2+2+1=5 bytes in the array `a` (`char a[5];`). You can figure out the rest, I hope?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Thank you very much for the help! I have figured the problem with your advice. Thank you!